# Защита приложения распространяющегося по подписке

Tags: c#, windows, защита

Подскажите как защищать приложения(Windows C#) от пиратства. На ум приходит загрузка части кода с сервера при запуске, но тут опять же проблема: взять эту часть кода когда подписка активна, когда подписка истекает, залить самому и закомпилить. И/или использовать шифрование, но насколько я понимаю, они тоже обходятся. И так вопрос: как защитить приложение, по максимуму, какой должна быть комплексная защита?

Примечание: подписки разные, поэтому как защитить от их подмены?

Comment: Кучу раз тут обсуждалось "как", кучу вопросов закрыли как "основан на мнениях". Каждый защищает свой проект так, как умеет и так, как хочет. Поймите только одно - все, что на компьютере клиента уже по сути является "утерянным", ибо чуть повозившись, взломается любая защита. Самое лучшее тут сервер, чтоб клиент лишь к нему подключался, а сервер уже обрабатывал запросы и выдавал результат. И помните, C# это открытый язык!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да не спорю, насчёт "потерянного", но согласитесь, если использовать много комплексных мер защиты, всегда можно дойти до состояния когда, легче купить подписку нежели взломать

Comment: @EvgeniyZ поэтому, подскажите пожалуйста, эти меры защиты, которые популярны и используются

Comment: `всегда можно дойти до состояния когда, легче купить подписку` - таких мер нету. Откройте любой торрент треккер и посмотрите, что там есть, найдете много популярного, от простых, мало известных программ, до крупных гигантов индустрии. Игры с Denuvo - взломаны, Visual Studio - взломана, Office - взломан, да даже Windows - взломана. Я даже больше скажу, некоторые проекты ломают годами (кстати, там эмуляция сервера идет, вот вам и плюс сервера), но все равно ломают. И тут вы, хотите защититься на открытом языке) Если ваш проект будет нужен, то любая защита будет взломана/обманута.

Comment: Нужно не загружать код с сервера, а выполнять его на сервере. То есть предоставлять услугу: [SaaS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Программное_обеспечение_как_услуга). Это фактически единственный способ как-то противостоять взлому.

Comment: ЗЫ: пишите быдлокод, тогда ни у кого не возникнет желания его украсть. :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ахахха, отличная идея, но подробнее по приложение анти детект браузера, я даже не догадываюсь, что там можно выполнять на сервере. Разве что попробовать создавать user data там

Comment: Вам же уже писали: в современных браузерах есть то, что вам нужно. То есть ваш "анти детект браузер" никому даром не нужен, т. к. уже реализован.

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем какой то анти детект делать внешним приложением, если все есть в браузерах и бесплатно. Так что ответ на вопрос с защитой простой - ничего защищать не надо, приложение которое никому не нужно и заменяется бесплатными средствами никто ломать не будет

Comment: А с "загружаемым с сервера кодом" вас очень быстро начнут блочить антивирусы и будут правы

Comment: @Mike спасибо, за предупреждение, учту)

Comment: @Mike в обычном браузере, можно сидеть во множестве аккаунтов, одного ресурса? Без вероятности бана?

Comment: Зависит от ресурса. Если вы хотите что-то накручивать - то создайте соответствующий вопрос.

Comment: @artemgh ну например для хрома есть плагин sessionBox. не знаю что там с проксями, если вы решили ip вдруг скрывать. Но плагинов для работы с проксями предостаточно. Еще есть знакомые, которые с помощью какого то я так понял стандартного средства сидят в десятке акков одного сайта. Не интересовался как то как они это делают, но средства точно есть. Надо погуглить, если интересно будет. И в любом случае подобное не делается внешним приложением, тут либо допиливается сам браузер, либо пишется расширение/плагин (как обычно все и делают)